# Django: multiple user types system and custom methods

Tags: python, django, subclass

I am working on a user organization in a django app that requires that one user-type creates tasks (Creator), and the other (Asignee), is assigned the task.  Creators can't assign tasks to other Creators, and Assignees can't create tasks.

Both of these models will need their own custom methods.  They will both use the same auth system.  However, discernment between the two will be important.

My current solution just uses one to one user profile classes and functions like the following to check membership:

```
def is_creator(user):
    try:
         if user.creator:
             return True
     except ObjectDoesNotExist:
         return False
```

Although this works, it gets to be a bit tedious.

**I was wondering if there was another way to implement this type of structure through subclassing all of my usertypes through a common profile class such that I can check membership this way:**

```
if request.user.profile.is_creator():
        pass
```

keeping in mind that both Creator and Assignee have completely different fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `user_type` field in the common profile and add a method in the same class:

```
@property
def is_creator(self):
    """Find out if this is a Creator user"""
    if self.user_type == "creator": 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```